# Google Spreadsheets e Javascript

Tags: javascript, google, cores

Recebo uma tabela com o conteúdo contendo vários produtos similares porem com linhas e códigos diferentes, outra informação importante é que algumas vezes já vem do meu cliente agrupados por cores.
Gostaria de fazer um *script* ou fórmula se for possível, em que eu agrupasse essas linhas de produtos semelhantes em apenas uma, concatenando os dados e conteúdos de linhas similares, para posteriormente eu pegar essa planilha e utilizar no indesign.

Documento exemplo: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BX9yYNgGSCiDO-VLEukt-k7pwbHk_b4wniKoJ4DYuWU/pubhtml

Eu consegui fazer algo parecido mas apenas para 2 linhas com uma fórmula no Google Spreadsheets. Exemplo:

```
=IF(A1>=A2;if(H1=H2;concatenate("0";B1;" ";C1;" /** ";"0";B2;" ";C2)))
```

Obs.: com esse código eu não consigo comparar mais de uma linha, e quando não existe outro produto similar, comparação ele também não funciona retornando `null`.

Acredito que a solução dependa de Javascript. Por favor me ajudem.

Answer (score -1):

Terás de criar uma função personalizada com Apps Script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Sua resposta não é clara o suficiente, e não soluciona o problema.

Comment: @mutley Claro que não soluciona, ele não esta trancado em alguma função que não sabe utilizar ou comando, ele não sabe nem por onde começar, se ele quiser a solução (função pronta) terá de contratar um programador, ou então começar a ler sobre apps-script. Consigo fazer essa função em 3 min, porém é melhor ele aprender a trabalhar com apps script.

Comment: Kriggs - Se é para responder dessa maneira, perdeu a oportunidade de ficar calado. Eu até já consegui fazer sozinho, digo estudando em vários sites - muinto embora não seja um programador. Agora se quer vender seus serviços, que é muito justo, aprenda o básico que é falar direito. Isso aqui é um forum de cooperação e eu estou pedindo ajuda como quase todos que estão aqui, tenho absoluta certeza que muito dos seus códigos foram aprendidos com perguntas como as minhas.